# Sum field by date range

Tags: solr, sum, facet

I'm using solr 3.6 and I'm kinda stuck trying to perform a special query.

I'm actually using facets by date range, the `face.date.gap` is set to `+1DAY`. Of course, the facet is supposed to return the count of docs at a date range but I also need to get the sum of a special field at the same ranges used in facet. It's like I need to count how many votes I have daily monthly, weekly, whatever... it depends on the gap params.

Any ideas? Should I use the group.query or facet.query?

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I have is to treat the weeks, days separately, and index them.  For ex. Today is part of 24th week.  Another suggestion is not to rule out multiple searches to service one request.  One to calculate all oth facets and one to return counts for given date range (based on search results from first query).